# Chrome extension to play music from Dropbox or Google Drive

Tags: chrome, music

I would like to listen to my personal MP3 files in Dropbox. When I go to www.dropbox.com and sign into my account, I can play music by simply clicking on MP3 files. Then a basic player pops up and you can listen to the song you picked. But the player isn’t anything special, and you can only listen to one song at a time.

I would like to have an extension that is able to play a list of music or a playlist file directly from Dropbox without downloading all of them.

I prefer Dropbox as cloud serivce, but if there is no solution with Dropbox, then Google Drive can be an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Enjoy music player](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enjoy-music-player/hncfgilfeieogcpghjnnhddghgdjbekl?hl=en)

[image]

> Enjoy Music Player version 3
>
> With Enjoy Music Player, you can play local and online music easily.
>
> Feature
>
> - In the new version, Enjoy Music Player will auto update the songs list from the  location you choose, when you new, deleted, renamed, or
>     moved  media files.
>
>   1. Brand new UI, rebuild and redesign
>   2. play local and online music
>   3. Google Drive integration, for streaming music directly from your Google Drive
>   4. Music Equalizer and  fade in/out effect
>   5. Mini mode
>   6. Better performance ...
>
> Shortcuts: If your Chrome version >= 35 you can manually add 
>   shortcuts by open the URL  chrome://extensions/configureCommands then
>   choose Enjoy Music Player  to set them.

[Video review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iAutBfPllg)

Answer (score 1):

For Google Drive you have [**Music Player for Google Drive**](http://www.driveplayer.com/), the [Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/music-player-for-google-d/hnfeekfpnjbdmelcapngdgkjnhgijjkh?hl=en-US) is just a link to that site. It is a simple music player that allows you to create, change, and load playlists:

> Music Player for Google Drive is a simple and lightweight online music
> player for your audio files stored in Google Drive.
> It lets you open music files directly from Google Drive or from its
> own interface.
> Music Player for Google Drive offers:
>
> - Playback of MP3 files, MP4, AAC (iTune's .m4a files), OGG (Audio only), WAV (Chrome only), webm (Audio).
> - Support for ID3 tags v1 and v2as well as AAC file Tags.
> - Automatic display of Album covers.
> - Playlist support (beta!).
> - Shuffle, repeat.
> - Handles users signed-in multiple Google account elegantly.
> - Open Audio files directly from the Google Drive UI.

[image: music player]

---

With [**Groove**](https://music.microsoft.com/) you can play songs directly from [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com), and you can also create playlists:

[image: groove player]

Comment: Wish I could assign shortcuts on keyboard to control the playback. The good point is being "open source"

Comment: In mean while I found an extension which is better, but tnx for your replay.